# Suppress Diagnostic Messages in Chrome for ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I tried to implement the [same logic](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/silencing-diagnostic-output-when-starting-webdrivers/) in Chrome and got an error. It would be great if someone could help me resolve the issue.

Code Written:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service old_initialize = instance_method(:initialize)      
    define_method(:initialize) do |executable_path, port, *extra_args|
            old_initialize.bind(self).call(executable_path, port, '--silent', *extra_args)
    end
end

#Starts without diagnostic output
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Error message obtained:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:36:in initialize
 from (irb):5:in call
 from (irb):5:in block in
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in new
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in default_service
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in initialize
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in new
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in for
```

I tried the alternative for this but that did not work. Code:

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Bridge
    old_extract_service_args = instance_method(:extract_service_args)
    define_method(:extract_service_args) do |opts|
        args = old_extract_service_args.bind(self).call(opts)
        if opts.has_key?(:service_silent) 
            opts.delete(:service_silent) 
            args << "--silent"
        end
        args
    end
end

#Starts without diagnostic output
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :service_silent => true

#Starts with diagnostic output
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Error Obtained :

```
undefined method `extract_service_args' for class `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Bridge' (NameError)
```

Comment: Hi Sushanth! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this tutorial on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And update your formatting so that the code is highlighted. I will do the first for you.

Answer (score 1):

The monkey patch that you are trying to execute was written for selenium-webdriver v2.33.0 (the latest version of the gem). Based on the exception, you are using v2.29.0, which did not have the `extra_args` parameter.

The best solution is to upgrade to your selenium-webdriver gem.

```
gem install selenium-webdrver
```

If you must use version 2.29.0 (with chromedriver v2.0), then you will have to do a different monkey patch.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Selenium
    module WebDriver
        module Chrome
            class Service
                def initialize(executable_path, port)
                    @uri           = URI.parse "http://#{Platform.localhost}:#{port}"
                    server_command = [executable_path, "--port=#{port}", "--silent"]

                    @process       = ChildProcess.build(*server_command)
                    @socket_poller = SocketPoller.new Platform.localhost, port, START_TIMEOUT

                    @process.io.inherit! if $DEBUG == true
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

The browser will start without the initial diagnostic messaging. Note that this does not address the chromedriver logging information, which is different (and again best handled by upgrading to version 2.33.0).

Comment: Thanks Justin i upgraded the selenium version and it worked out. Implemented the code for chrome driver logging information.